# Raabe's Integral

Tags: numerical-integration

Raabe's integral formula says

$\int^1_0$ Log$~ \Gamma(p+t)dt=p$Log $ p-p +\ln\sqrt{2\pi}$

Here Log is the Principal Branch.

Take

```
a =.3;
x=3;
s=2;
p=1+x/a^2+I*s/a;
NIntegrate[Log[Gamma[p+t},{t,0,1}]
p*Log[p]-p+Log[Sqrt[2*Pi]]
```

When I run this code I get :
$
  87.349 -1.5172 I\\
  87.349 +23.6155 I
$

Is Mathematica using a different branch of the logarithm?

Comment: Up to Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Ludwig_Raabe, the parameter $p$ should be positive, but your $p=\frac{103}{3}+\frac{20 i}{3}$.

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276592/raabes-integral-for-complex-argument . The arguments of Daniel Fischer do not seem to be solid.

Answer (score 3):

Using the values you give, but ensuring exact values

```
a = 3/10;
x = 3;
s = 2;
p = 1 + x/a^2 + I*s/a;
```

and using `LogGamma` (see help to understand its special properties)

```
FullSimplify[
 Integrate[LogGamma[p + t], {t, 0, 1}] == 
  p Log[p] - p + Log[Sqrt[2 π]]]
(* True *)
```

we see that your equality holds.  So you are probably correct in assuming that `Log[Gamma[]]` gets you on the wrong branch.

As stated in the documentation "`LogGamma[z]` is analytic throughout the complex `z` plane, except for a single branch cut discontinuity along the negative real axis. `Log[Gamma[z]]` has a more complex branch cut structure."  As I understand this, `LogGamma` can be defined with a simple branch cut.  The conventional definitions of `Log` and `Gamma` give something more complicated.

**UPDATE**

In fact, if we don't assign a value to `p`, Mathematica gives

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[LogGamma[p + t], {t, 0, 1}] ==
   p Log[p] - p + Log[Sqrt[2 π]]]
(* True *)
```

suggesting that the equality holds for all values of `p` in the complex plane.

NB. I add this in order to delete my downvote.@user 64494.

Comment: Interestingly, if you write   p Log[p] - p + Log[Sqrt[2 π]]]  as   -p+(-1+p) Log[p]+ Log[Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]]+Log[Gamma[1+p]]-LogGamma[p]   you get   87.349-1.5172 i

Comment: Obviously, these two  expressions are equivalent.  Why does Mathematica give two different answers?  Is there a branch change and why?.  This is not good if you are trying to use Mathematica to validate numerically some of your results.

Comment: -1. The numerical calculations a = 3/10;
x = 3;
s = 2;
p = 1 + x/a^2 + I * s/a;
NIntegrate[Log[Gamma[p + t]], {t, 0, 1}]
N[p*Log[p] - p + Log[Sqrt[2*Pi]]] do not confirm the Raabe's formula for complex value of  $p$.

Comment: As far as I understand it, LogGamma[z_]:=Integrate[D[Gamma[w],w]/Gamma[w],{w,1,z}] . The integral is taken over the closed interval from 1 to z.

Comment: @mikado: I changed my mind. You saw the heart of the problem.